# django- how would I create a sort for a query to put one specific element first, then remaining by some field?

Tags: python, django, sorting, django-rest-framework

Specifically, I am looking to get a query of users.  My `User` model has a `first_name` and `last_name` field.  What I need to do is order the `request.user` at the top of the results, and the remaining users in alphabetical order by `last_name, first_name`.  The last part is easy:

```
q = User.objects.all().order_by('last_name', 'first_name')
```

However I am not sure how to ensure that the `request.user` is the first result in the query.  This is all being done for a django rest framework view, and thus (I believe) I need to have it done through a query which is passed on to the serializer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, it might be better design to not do this. Have some other endpoint that returns your own user object if you need it, and in the list view treat yourself no differently. But if you really neeed to.

You probably could use an annotation.

```
User.objects.annotate(is_me=Case(
            When(pk=request.user.pk, then=Value(True)), 
            When(pk__ne=request.user.pk, then=Value(False)),
         output_field=BooleanField())
 ).order_by('-is_me')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't really need the result to be a queryset you can try the following:

```
import itertools
me = request.user
others = User.objects.exclude(id=me.pk)
users_list = itertools.chain([me], others)
```